# How to configure NLog to only log certain levels in uppercase

Tags: formatting, nlog

My format contains:

```
layout="${longdate} ${pad:padding=-5:inner=${uppercase:${level}}} ...
```

That pads an uppercase version of the log level into the file.

I'd like to uppercase only warnings and above, so that it's easier to quickly scan for them.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`${when}`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer) layout renderer.

e.g.

```
layout="${longdate} ${pad:padding=-5:inner=${when:when=level>=LogLevel.Warn:inner=${uppercase:${level}}:else=${level}}} ...
```

Comment: @DrewNoakes I can remove the "not tested"? :)

Comment: Haha, yes, finally got around to putting it through it's paces.